# How can I convert a data object to a file?

Tags: javascript

I have an Object that has same structure of data of a File Object

```
{
    lastModified: 1587700504077
    lastModifiedDate: Fri Apr 24 2020 11:55:04 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)
    name: "37-373238_black-sticker-black-flower-transparent-aesthetic-hd-png.png"
    size: 227226
    type: "image/png"
}
```

I want this data to be converted into File Object. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: *"I want this data to be converted into File Object. Is there a way to do this?"* No, not literally. But this sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve by turning it into a `File` object?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder will be using it to display in bootstrap Form File. I actually did this because I'm using VueJS and props don't have File type so I convert it to Object first so I can send it to my component

Comment: *"will be using it to display in bootstrap Form File"* If you mean you'll be using it in an `input typ="file"` input or anything else that would read a file from the user's machine, you simply cannot do that on the browser, full stop.

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert that object to a file (at least, not to a file that represents a PNG image with a size of 227226 bytes of useful data). It contains a lot of metadata **about** a file, but none of the **content** of that file.